# jquery: limit adding blocks

Tags: jquery

```
 <div id="more"> </div>  
     <a id="add">Add more</a> 

    <script>    
    var i=1;
    do{   
    $(function(){
    $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#more").append("textblock");
    });
    });
    i++;
    } while(i<=5);  
    </script>
```

How to stop adding textblocks after reaching 5 times?  Thanks!

Comment: Uh... what is your code trying to achieve there? It kind of looks like you're attaching the same event handler 5 times over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the click event handler after reaching `5` by using [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method. Although the while loop doesn't make any sense which would bind the handler `5` times so clicking once would append 5 times.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="more"></div>
<a id="add">Add more</a> 

<script>
  var i = 1;
  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#more").append("textblock");
    if (i++ == 5) $("#add").off('click');
  });
</script>
```